# PHP fgetcsv with not valid CSV file

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with content:

```html
Центральный;Московская область;117036;PC;JEEP;GRAND CHEROKEE;ДЖИП ГРАНД ЧЕРОКИ;В;01.01.0001;08.05.2014;2004;1J8G2Е8N94У161064;-;1J8G2Е8N94У161064;-;94;2;227;4701;1;1;29;2495;2073;ФИЗ ЛИЦО;-;АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИЙ (ЮЗАО) Р-Н;-;-;-
Центральный;Московская область;117036;PC;VAZ;LARGUS;ЛАДА ЛАРГУС FS015L;В;01.01.0001;08.05.2014;2014;ХТАFS015LЕ0811430;UА46515;ХТАFS015LЕ0811430;-;11;1;84;1598;1;1;09;2010;1260;"АЗИЯ МАТЕРИАЛ ХЭНДЛИНГ ООО;7728814946;АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИЙ (ЮЗАО) Р-Н;-;КРЖИЖАНОВСКОГО;2|21
Центральный;Московская область;117208;PC;TOYOTA;LANDCRUISER;ТОЙОТА ЛЕНД КРУЗЕР ПРАДО;В;01.01.0001;08.05.2014;2001;JТЕВN99J100077420;1122027;JТЕВN99J100077420;JТЕВN99J100077420;94;2;178;3378;1;1;21;2680;1900;ФИЗ ЛИЦО;-;ЧЕРТАНОВО СЕВЕРНОЕ (ЮАО) Р-Н;-;-;-
```

I tried import this CSV to SQL DB with this while loop:

```html
while (($csv_data = fgetcsv($csv_file, 10000, ';', '"')) !== false) {
  //some stuff
}
```

In this CSV file I have 3 records, but in SQL I see only 2. Problem in this line:

;1260;"АЗИЯ МАТЕРИАЛ ХЭНДЛИНГ ООО;7728814946;

Problen in extra character " before АЗИЯ. How I can correctly parse this CSV file? File is more then 200 Mb.

Comment: _Don’t_ specify `"` as enclosure, _if_ you don’t need it for any of the rest of the data. If you do need it - then you will have to fix this manually somehow, `fgetcsv` will probably not be able to _guess_ when it is meant to be an enclosure character, and when just data.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you. I also tried this code fgetcsv($csv_file, 10000, ';') but result the same.

Comment: Of course - `$enclosure` is an _optional_ parameter, with the default value `"`. So you are effectively still doing the exact same thing, only implicitly instead of explicitly. Try and specify an empty string (if PHP accepts that, didn’t check) - and if not, find _some_ character that’s never going to be part of your data (if you can.)

Comment: @CBroe, thank you! Empty string is not working, but it is works with \s symbol:
fgetcsv($csv_file, 10000, ';', '\s')

I receive many Notices: Notice: fgetcsv(): enclosure must be a single character in  but it is OK :)

Comment: This only takes one character, so if you specified `\s` as the value for this parameter, your enclosure character _is_ effectively just \ - so if \ can ever be part of your _data_, this would still fail in such places.

Comment: @CBroe, I already tested with \s - works OK

Answer (score 0):

===== EDIT =======

Okay, obviously your CSV gets not parsed right I used different data and thought CSV is CSV and that example worked just as fine idk. Now it works with your data. Only problem is your `"`, this is causing problems

[image]

(I replaced your first element because I don't speak Russian and I cannot see differences in words)

```php
$file_data = array_filter(explode("\n", file_get_contents("data.csv")));
$data = array();

foreach ($file_data as $key => $row) {
  $data[] = str_getcsv($row, ';', '', "\\");
}

print_r($data);
```

===== OLD MESSAGE =======

I tried this PHP example and it worked just as fine.

```php
/*
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in roe $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
*/
```

Comment: Hello. Why , delimeter? Your code didn't work with csv example in question. I find out this solution: fgetcsv($csv_file, 10000, ';', '\s')